# How to edit the WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have copied the WooCommerce files from my plugins file into my theme file so that I can edit / overwrite them. Now I want to be able to find the html files so I can remove certain sections like the search bar and page links in the sidebar. I also need to find the html as I would like to make this plugin work with bootstrap. Which files do I need to find to make these kinds of changes?
I've tried looking and all I can find is php code. Or is this not the way I should be trying to achieve this? Thanks

This is what I'm getting by default as you can see all of my page links are in the sidebar along with a search bar.
[image]

Comment: You will need the template files... but the template files also tend to be PHP. Looks for files name `template-*.php`. I would advise looking at some basic Wordpress theme tutorials. This isn't the place for these types of questions as they're *far* too broad.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [adding WooCommerce support to your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/#section-5)? And I would strongly advise you *not* copy every template file into your theme. Only copy the ones you absolutely need to. (With all the hooks and filters available this should not be that many) I've had to rescue too many sites that break when WooCommerce upgrades and the theme templates are out of date.

Comment: The PHP files contain the HTML you're trying to adjust - but often you'll find the particular HTML you need in an included file. Adding a CSS framework to the mix will be a bigger project than you're expecting, because the HTML is simply in so very many places it's going to be almost impossible to replace it all. Every time WooCommerce is updated, you'll have to update all the PHP files in the theme to match. So, your best option is likely to be: find a new theme that explicitly supports WooCommerce (it's likely one based on Bootstrap exists) and then create a child theme for customizations.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks for the advice. My problem is that I have created a custom theme and the site is fully developed. And now I need a WooCommerce shop page if I created a child theme I would lose all my work so far wouldn't I?

Comment: If you created a custom theme that includes all of the WooCommerce templates, you've already signed up for a huge lot of maintenance. Every time Woo updates you'll have to update all of your theme files. So it's actually going to be less work in the long run if you find an actively supported parent theme with Bootstrap that is at least fairly similar to what you're going for, then create a child theme that applies your additional styles and customizations. That way when Woo updates you will only have to update a file or two.

Comment: Updates aside, if you just want to affect the shop page and you already have a custom theme, read through the Woo themes documents and also through the codebase to figure out which file you need to edit, and just edit that.